# Uploading APK file error “The picture in the apk is invalid.”

Tags: android

I got an error `Upload failed.The picture in the apk is invalid.` when I uploaded my **.apk** file to to the Google Play market.

All the images file type is either .gif or .png in my package.

Besides, I searched some answers about the uploading error here but it didn't work .Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm new in the android. I can't understand it .Is the logat in the eclipse or the google play website ? Thanks for replying:)

Comment: its in eclipse..whats ur email address?

Comment: s3744102@yahoo.com.tw 
May I have your address? I'll send the locat message to u.

Answer (score 0):

while u uploading the APK file check the size of the promo image and other image sizes that specified in the rule of uploading the image in play.google.com

thank you,

Comment: Sorry , I can't find any rulee of uploading the image in play.google.com . But I searched something about resource-drawable in the following website. It talked a image file type limit but no sizes limit .
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html 
 
I really thank you for replying :)

Answer (score 0):

you may check that there is any image which extension was manually change.

Comment: Sorry, My English ability is poor. I can't understand what you said fully . I manually change all images in four drawalbe folders in order to apply in the 3:4:6:8 scaling ratio for supporting multiple screens. By the way , the biggest image in my package is 480*800.
 I really thank you for replying :)

Comment: As android support some certain format of the images (jpg, png etc), suppose you have a image with extension with .xyz and by renaming the image you changed it to .jpg manually and added to resource. It will not work at all. If you did so, change the extension by saving correct format using Photoshop. Also you can check Icon image size (72x72). Hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: That is , a image named a.jpg is in the drawable-mdpi , but it's not  simultaneously in other three drawable folders.